How do await and Promise.resolve() test whether their arg is a thenable?
I would like to be able to reason about what await will do when it is called on various kinds of values.
The MDN documentation for await describes the decision procedure for that, one of the steps which is to decide whether the object is a thenable (after it has determined it isn't a Native Promise):

The expression is resolved in the same way as Promise.resolve(): it's always converted to a native Promise and then awaited. If the expression is a:

Native Promise [...]
Thenable object (including non-native promises, polyfill, proxy, child class, etc.): [...]
[...]


(And the linked doc for Promise.resolve() also says essentially
the same thing-- in particular, it links to the same section on Thenable object in the Promise documentation).
So, following that link for Thenable object, still looking for a precise definition of Thenable object as it is used in the decision procedure (i.e. exactly how await and Promise.resolve() test for it, in that decision procedure):

A thenable implements the .then() method, which is called with two callbacks: one for when the promise is fulfilled, one for when it's rejected.

That's the closest thing I see to an answer on this page, but it's not an answer.
(E.g. is the thing, which is known to be a non-Native-Promise, considered to be a thenable if attempting to get its then property doesn't throw?  Or, doesn't it throw and returns non-undefined?  Or, doesn't throw and returns something whose typeof is function?  Or, doesn't throw and returns something such that calling it with two callbacks doesn't throw? Etc.; there are lots of possibilities, and I'm sure this is nailed down in a spec somewhere.)
My precise question is: Exactly how do await and Promise.resolve() decide whether to treat their argument (once it's decided that it's a non-Native-Promise) as a Thenable object, for the purposes of the decision procedure quoted above?
(Note: this question is about the ES8 await operator and ES6 Promises; it isn't about bluebird or promises/A+ or any other promises implementation/spec, so previous questions/answers about those are not applicable.)

This ..?

Have a look here or there


Is the thing considered to be a thenable iff attempting to get its then property doesn't throw and returns something whose typeof is function?

Yes, very much that. You can find this specified in §27.2.1.3.2 Promise Resolve Functions, the procedure to resolve a promise with a value that is used by new Promise, Promise.resolve and (by extension) await. This still conforms to the Promises/A+ resolution procedure and its definition of "thenable".

I see.  With the nuance that (if I'm reading correctly) if attempting to get the then property does throw, then that doesn't make it a non-thenable for the purposes of this decision procedure; rather, that turns into a "rejected".   Looks like the spec is very much needed in order to answer this question; that MDN page description serves as a rough outline of the behavior but it doesn't even come close to helping answer it for specific cases.

Well if accessing then throws, it's not a method… And in general any exceptions during the resolution procedure get turned into rejections, no different for the constructor executor callback, the .then accessor or the actual method call.

That sounds like a good way of thinking about it and remembering it, although I don't see that general principle pointed out anywhere in those three MDN pages, nor in the spec section you pointed to.  Is that from somewhere specific in the spec or docs?  Or does one just have to deduce it from reading all the specific clauses, and/or from knowing the rationale behind those spec clauses?

I'd say it's just the general rationale that ignoring exceptions is bad and turning them into rejections is the reasonable thing to do
